# Oracle Database Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am getting the character string buffer too small error on the field below.

`DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(DW.RESPONSE.OPTION_VALUE)` is in the select statement that is causing the error. It is a `CLOB` data type.

I really am only looking for the word 'yes' so is there a way to limit the results or stop the error? I've tried the following but still get the same error.

```
UPPER(TRIM(CAST(DW.RESPONSE.OPTION_VALUE AS VARCHAR(100))))     
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(DW.RESPONSE.OPTION_VALUE,8000)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the complete SQL

Comment: try to split the clob by 4000 per each portion (such as 1..4000, 4001..8000 by substr), not 8000

Comment: how do I split it that way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find the word or phrase 'YES' why not use the INSTR function?
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651